# jquery "this" preventing access to containing object "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've run into this a few times now. I've tried to create the simplest code snippet I could to demonstrate it.

The problem is, inside and object method, if I pass an anonymous function to a jQuery method (like an "each"), inside of the function, I lose access to the object's "this". Because "this" is now related to the jQuery object.

See the comments in the middle of the `logNameAndElementIds` method for the crux of the problem:

(I'm using Crockford's object function to produce an object instance based on an object defined with an object literal.)

```
Object.create = function (o) {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = o;
    return new F();
};


var objectLiteral = {

    setName: function(name){
        this.name = name;
    },

    logNameAndElementIds: function(){

        // works fine, 'this' refers to object instance
        console.log( this.name );

        $('.foo').each(function(){

             // we've lost "this" because it now refers to jQuery
            console.log( this.name ); 
            console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
        });
    }

};

obj1 = Object.create(objectLiteral);
obj1.setName('Mike');
obj1.logNameAndElementIds();
```

What's the right way to handle or workaround this sort of situation?

Obviously my example is stupid, but it's just to demonstrate a point.  More often I want to loop through a jQuery matched set, then call a method of the containing object on each item. But I can't access the object's method, because I now have jQuery's "this".

Comment: Are you aware that you are overwriting an existing [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)?

Comment: Welcome to one of the pitfalls of javascript IMHO. I like to use an external library called underscore. Check it out http://underscorejs.org/, the bind function is particularly useful for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a better answer to this than the one I previously accepted, and that is to use ES5's new [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method. Much cleaner, available in all modern browsers, and easy to shim for older browsers.

With bind() you can do stuff like this:

```
var myObj = {
    name: "Foo";

    iterateParagraphs: function() {
        $("p").each(function(i,p){
            $(p).addClass("bar"); // use $(p) where you use to use $(this);
            $(p).text(this.name); // this refers to myObj = Foo
        }.bind(this)); // get this (myObj) into callback
    }
};
```

A minified version of the Mozilla shim (which seems to be the best around) is:

```
Function.prototype.bind||(Function.prototype.bind=function(b){if("function"!==typeof this)throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");var d=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,1),e=this,a=function(){},c=function(){return e.apply(this instanceof a&&b?this:b,d.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)))};a.prototype=this.prototype;c.prototype=new a;return c});
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you get around this problem is to save `this` to a variable that you can access within the new scope.

Looking at your logNameAndElementIds function:

```
logNameAndElementIds: function(){

    // works fine, 'this' refers to object instance
    console.log( this.name );
    var that = this;

    $('.foo').each(function(){

        // we've lost "this" because it now refers to jQuery
        console.log( that.name ); 
        console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
    });
}
```

Comment: yeah, I get this, but isn't it kind of awkward and memory intensive to keep copying 'this' to a local variable? especially if you do this for a number of the object methods? there's not some sort of more elegant way to handle this?

Comment: You can always use .call() where you can specify the context, so you could do .each.call(this, function() { /* Do something in here as this will = what it was outside */ });

Comment: It is somewhat awkward I agree. That is how scope works in javascript. You shouldn't feel any significant consequences in terms of wasting memory. Javascript handles garbage collection for you.

As far as I know there is no more elegant way to handle this other than using an external library. Someone mentioned underscore. But my guess is that it's doing something similar just hiding the "ugly" part from you. There are plenty more JS gotcha's too :)

Comment: upon further research, I think using Function.prototype.bind is a better, more elegant way of handling these situations, see my new accepted answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The value of the 'pointer' `this` changes depending on the scope of the function block. To reference the `this` from the outer-scope, save a copy of the original object `this` (a common convention is saving it as `self`):

```
var objectLiteral = {

    setName: function(name){
        this.name = name;
    },

    logNameAndElementIds: function(){

        // works fine, 'this' refers to object instance
        console.log( this.name );

        var self = this;

        $('.foo').each(function(){

            //use 'self' instead of 'this'

            console.log( self.name ); 
            console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
        });
    }

};
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using "self" rather than "this" in the .each()?

Comment: @starskythehutch I am, I just didnt modify his original code...I'll change it, probably clearer that way

Answer (score 0):

This is known thing. Usually we use a proxy for original `this`.

```
    var that = this;
    $('.foo').each(function(){

        console.log( that ); // original object
        console.log( this ); 


    });
```